# svn E210002: Network connection closed unexpectedly In a Middle of Session on Window 10

Tags: svn, ssh, subversive

I have recently migrated to window 10, and updated Subversion 1.8.17 and TortoiseSVN 1.9.7 client. 
I am facing weird issue of with SVN checkout E210002: Network connection closed unexpectedly while checking out project which is greater than 30MB and it works fine with other project which is less than 30 MB.
I get same error with Eclipse,  Tortoise client and from command line

I am using svn+ssh protocol. 
svn checkout svn+ssh://svnadmin@foo.com/blah blah

Comment: Contact your admin and check your firewall, proxy and antivirus.

Comment: Firewall and proxies cannot be applicable as repository is hosted on intranet and  antivirus does not seems to be issue my other colleague is accessing with window 10 but on different laptop model